# d3 - rendering an html table on top of an svg element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, xhtml

I am trying to dynamically create html tables using d3. They will need to be draggable and use other svg features so they need to be created inside an svg element. Since svg doesn't allow tables, I have created the table inside a foreign object. I can't write out the html template first because I don't know how many rows/columns etc will be passed through in the data. I have the html part working but it is not allowing me to convert it into the right format using 'xhtml:element':

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');
          svg.append("foreignObject")
          .attr("width", 200)
          .attr("height", 400);
          var table = d3.select('foreignObject').append("xhtml:table");

          // append header row
          table.append('xhtml:thead').append('xhtml:tr')
          .selectAll('xhtml:th')
          .data(scope.columns).enter()
          .append('xhtml:th')
          .attr('class', function (d) { return d.cl; })
          .text(function (d) { return d.head; });

          // append body rows
          table.append('xhtml:tbody')
          .selectAll('xhtml:tr')
          .data(scope.movies).enter()
          .append('xhtml:tr')
          .selectAll('xhtml:td')
          .data(function (row, i) {
            // evaluate column objects against the current row
            return scope.columns.map(function (c) {
              var cell = {};
              d3.keys(c).forEach(function (k) {
                cell[k] = typeof c[k] == 'function' ? c[k](row, i) : c[k];
              });
              return cell;
            });
          }).enter()
          .append('xhtml:td')
          .html(function (d) { return d.html; })
          .attr('class', function (d) { return d.cl; });
```

Here are the sample data sets I'm testing out with:

```
scope.movies = [
            { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972, length: 175,
              budget: 6000000, rating: 9.1 },
            { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994,
              length: 142, budget: 25000000, rating: 9.1 },
            { title: "The Lord of the Rings 3", year: 2003,
              length: 251, budget: 94000000, rating: 9 }
        ];
        scope.columns = [
            { head: 'Movie title', cl: 'title', html: function (d) { return d.title; } },
            { head: 'Year', cl: 'center', html: function (d) { return d.year; } },
            { head: 'Length', cl: 'center', html: function (d) { return d.length; } },
            { head: 'Budget', cl: 'num', html: function (d) { return d.budget; } },
            { head: 'Rating', cl: 'num', html: function (d) { return d.rating; } }
        ];
```

Currently in this format, I am getting the error:
'Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': 'xhtml:th' is not a valid selector.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no good reason why `.selectAll('xhtml:td')` is not working may be this is not supported.

But i tried the following and it worked thought of sharing with you:

```
var table = svg.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", 480)
  .attr("height", 500)
  .append("xhtml:body")//append body to foreign object(this is missing in your code)
```

Then you can simply append elements as you used to do in d3 like below.

```
table.append("table")
  // append header row
table.append('thead').append('tr')
  .selectAll('th')//select using normal selector without xhtml
  .data(scope.columns).enter()
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BmfrpUEK0f5F1qp7uuKX?p=preview)

Hope this helps!